# Upload a file in MVC without form tags

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a colorbox pop-up where I am displaying my view - UploadDocument. In this view I am having file upload element (type="file" ) and a textbox.

Here is the code for colorbox-

```
 parent.parent.$.fn.colorbox({
                            href: url +  '?callingWindow=' + window.frameElement.id,
                            open: true,
                            iframe: true,
                            width: "450px",
                            height: "300px",
                            title: "Upload Document",
                            close: '<button id=\"Save\">Save</button><button id=\"Cancel\">Cancel</button>',
                            onClosed: false
                        });
```

UploadDocument view is -

```
<h4 class="resume">Upload a document to presentation </h4>
    <div class="description">Please click on the link below to add documents to your presentation.</div>

    <table id="fieldsTable" class="tblFields">
    <tr>
    <td class="description">Choose file:</td>
        <td> <input id="fileDialog" type="file" name="file"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="description">Description:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="docFileName" style="width: 225px;"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" width="300px"><span class="errorMessage" id="spanErrorMessage"></span></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

On my view I am calling Post method of controller action on Save button's click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
parent.$('#Save').click(function() {
             $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UploadDocument", "MyController")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { id: cmaId},
                    success: function () {
                        alert('added to temp');
                    }
                });
});
</script>
```

Now when I call the action method UploadDocument with HttpPostedFileBase as a parameter. It is null all the time.

Is it because for this to work we have to have a  tag and type=submit ? 
Since I can not do it here as Save button is not part of the view, but it's parent, is there any alternative for doing this with a normal button click and without any form tags ?

Comment: uploading file without form tag is just not possible..

Comment: what is stopping you from having a form and a submit button?

Comment: Becuase the Save button is part of Colorbox and not the view. Had it been the case where in my view I had a button it would have been lot easier.

Comment: are you using the colorbox to upload the file or just to show the  content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File uploads over an ajax call do not work like you seem to believe they do -- you simply can't post the form values like it's a standard form post with a few text boxes.

There are a couple of plugins out there that can help you out however, or depending on your requirements you can leverage [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) -- here's your code with formdata:

```
parent.$('#Save').click(function() {
    var data = new FormData();
    fd.append("id", cmaId);
    fd.append("fileDialog", $("#fileDialog")[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UploadDocument", "MyController")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
            alert('added to temp');
        }
    });
});
```

I didn't run this, it's rough but it should give you enough to get started.  If you are going to use jQuery with FormData then be aware that the contentType + processData options need to be set to false so jQuery doesn't alter your post data/headers.

Comment: Thanks a lot Disgone for making it clear how file upload over ajax should work. Only change I had to do in above code was in fileDialog. the value is stored at - $('#fileDialog')[0].files[0]